# Wordpress - wp_get_object_terms - multiple taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, shortcode, taxonomy

I am currently using the following to fetch the terms from my taxonomy:

```
 $taxonomy = 'books';
 $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids'));

 if ( empty($post_terms) )
 return false;

 $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false) );
```

Now I need to extend the code for another 2 taxonomies 'cds' and 'magazines'.

I was hoping to fix it with by adding array like this:

```
 $taxonomy = array(
                'books', 
                'cds', 
                'magazines'
 );
 $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('fields' => 'ids'));

 if ( empty($post_terms) )
 return false;

 $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false) );
```

But that doesn't actually seem to work.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve multiple terms from multiple taxonomies than you have to pass all your taxonomies as array like below.

```
$post_terms= get_terms(
          'taxonomy' => array(
                         'books',
                         'cds',
                         'magazines')
);
```

Tested and works well.

Comment: Thanks Raju, so how do I then declare the $taxonomy value? Would you be able to place your solution into my code?